# Hide zeros in an array in Excel

Tags: excel-formula

I am compiling an overview of different sheets in Excel in a new sheet and am referencing different arrays from the sheets with special formulas, similar to "=A1:C10". However, since some of the cells are empty in the source arrays, the destination shows zeros in those cells. Is there a way to suppress those zeros? They should just be empty cells.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this number format to hide zeros:

```
0;-0;;@
```

Or use a conditional formatting to set the font color same as background.

You may, of course, make a conditional formula like

```
=IF(<something not zero>,<this value>,"")
```

But from Excel point of view this will change nothing - `""` will still convert to `0` value when passed to another calculation.

Answer (score 1):

On the Tools menu, click Options, and then click the View tab. To display zero values as blank cells, clear the check box.